# Finding number of point features located within a polygon layer using L.esri.query

Tags: leaflet, spatial-query, esri-leaflet

I am new to JavaScript and Leaflet, so please bear with me. I am working on a Leaflet map in which I am calling in two separate REST layers, a point layer (heritage trees) and polygon layer (neighborhoods), using L.esri.featureLayer. What I would like to do is add functionality to the neighborhood polygon layer in which a popup is displayed with the number of heritage trees that are located within a given neighborhood when it is clicked by the user. Because I am already using the L.esri plugin, I'm trying to do this using the L.esri.query functionality, but can't figure out how to get it to work. Here is the JavaScript I have so far:

```
//Define neighborhoods feature layer
var nbohoods = L.esri.featureLayer({
url:'https://www.portlandmaps.com/arcgis/rest/services/Public/COP_OpenData/MapServer/3',
minZoom: 12,
opacity: 20,
onEachFeature: function(layer){
    //define trees as query layer
    var trees = L.esri.query({
        url: 'https://www.portlandmaps.com/arcgis/rest/services/Public/COP_OpenData/MapServer/26',
        }).within(nbohoods);
    }
});

nbohoods.bindPopup(function (layer) {
    return L.Util.template("<p><strong>Neighborhood Name: </strong> {MAPLABEL}</p>", layer.feature.properties 
                      );
});
```

I know I'm not referencing the results of the function in the popup at the end (I don't know how) and I'm also not sure how to access the geometry of the nbohoods variable. Any ideas for how I can get this to work?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/40302642/125400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use the `onEachFeature` event. Insted, in the `bindPopup` function, you want to just show a temporary message:

```
nbohoods.bindPopup(function (layer) {
  // return temporary message while the "queryTrees" function called from the popupopen function runs:
    return L.Util.template('getting tree info ...');
});
```

And then you want to setup an event listener for the `popupopen` event, and this is where you'll kick off your query from. You do this because the `popupopen` event gives you both the layer/feature clicked and a reference to the open popup.

```
nbohoods.on('popupopen', function(evt) {
    queryTrees(evt.layer.feature, evt.popup);
});
```

Finally, define the `queryTrees` function that we're using above, that takes in a feature and a reference to the popup. It will do the query then update the popup when the query is complete.

```
var queryTrees = function(feature, popup) {
  L.esri.query({
    url:'https://www.portlandmaps.com/arcgis/rest/services/Public/COP_OpenData/MapServer/26'
  })
  .within(feature)
  .run(function(error, featureCollection) {
    // this function is called when the query is complete. Update the currently open popup.
    popup.setContent(L.Util.template('Number of Trees: ' + featureCollection.features.length));
  }.bind(this));
}
```

Putting it all together, [here's a sample](https://jsfiddle.net/gavinr/rn941cwa/) with it all working.